# Excel Date Picker Sub Crashes When Row or Column is Selected

Tags: excel, vba, datepicker, crash, runtime

I have added a Date Picker to an Excel table with the Private Sub below.  When I select a row or column I get a Run-Time Error 1004.  When I select Debug the line below is highlighed as the error:

***.Left = Target.Offset(0, 1).Left***

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
 
 With Sheet1.DTPicker1
    .Height = 20
    .Width = 20
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A7:B135,J7:J135")) Is Nothing Then
      .Visible = True
      .Top = Target.Top
      .Left = Target.Offset(0, 1).Left
      .LinkedCell = Target.Address
    Else
      .Visible = False
    End If
  End With
End Sub
```

Many thanks in advance for any assisstance

Nick

Answer (score 0):

It's best to use `Intersect` to create a new range and use that in place of `Target`

Something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim rng As Range
   
   With Sheet1.DTPicker1
       .Height = 20
       .Width = 20
       
       Set rng = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A7:B135,J7:J135"))
       if rng Is Nothing then
           .Visible = False
       Else
           if rng.cells.count > 1 Then
               .Visible = False
           else 
               .Visible = True
               .Top = rng.Top
               .Left = rng.Offset(0, 1).Left
               .LinkedCell = rng.Address
           End if
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```